# Is while(boolean method); a bad practice? (Example)

Tags: java

I really like the mechanism and style of this code, but Im kinda unaware if this coding style is appropriate or a bad practice.

```
public class Test 
{
    private static int counter;
    private final static ArrayList<Object> _objects = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //iterate till you find a valid object randomly
        while (!doStuffIfValid(_objects.get(Rnd.get(_objects.size()))));
    }

    public static boolean doStuffIfValid(Object obj)
    {
        if (++counter > 30)
           return true; //dont try more than 30 times
        // if condition
        // {
        //      //do stuff then exit the caller loop
        //      return true;
        // }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling a boolean method in `while` condition is not bad; making that method cause *side effects* usually is.

Comment: You just have to make sure to make the boolean false at some point otherwise it will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Basically I know that calling a method in while is normal in java, my question is if the style of this class is a good practice not the while(method) itself, if you notice my while loop is strange

Comment: @CodeWhisperer indeed

Comment: You don't technically have to make the statement false. `while(true) {break;} System.out.println("Foo");` will print Foo. Is it neat? Not really, since a 3rd party won't know what's causing the break without reading the code, but it technically works.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

The answer to that lies within the boolean method. If that method is bloated, and resource heavy; then no.

Also, if you're randomly checking objects, it may be a better idea to instead: eliminate the objects you know aren't valid from a list, then randomly select from that list.

This way the pseudo-randomizer doesn't (by chance) select invalid objects to validate over, and over again; and waste time/resources.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using a boolean method as a condition for a while-loop. However, stuffing loop functionality in the loop header is, generally, a bad practice. It leads to a code which is difficult to understand, debug (breakpoints become inconvenient) and maintain.